# Mail client independent address and calendar program?

Tags: email, calendar, pim

Dose Ubuntu have any plans in future to integrate a mail client independent address and calendar program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such plans exist.  If you would like a recommendation on an address book that'll work with the panel applet and a calendar that'll work with the clock applet without forcing you to setup Evolution mail, look at [contacts](http://packages.ubuntu.com/contacts) [image: Install contacts] and [dates](http://packages.ubuntu.com/dates) [image: Install dates]

Comment: is there any standalone calendar program supporting gmail and the panel applet, or is this hopeless. I am completely unsatisfied with evolutions dull performance, google webcalender even reacts much faster

Comment: @Marcel there was (e.g. [Mulberry](http://www.mulberrymail.com/) or [Chandler](http://chandlerproject.org/), also check [here](http://davical.org/clients.php)). But it looks like with [Gnome v3](https://www.gnome.org/gnome-3/) there will be calendar and addressbook integration. Also check these posts: [1](http://askubuntu.com/q/408588/156568) [2](http://askubuntu.com/q/408584/156568)

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays when corporations and "intelligence" agencies intercept our daily communication which is all based to a consitent PIM (Personal Information Management) GNU/Linux OS still cannot provide easy-to-use calendar and addressbook solution.

[Contacts](http://packages.ubuntu.com/contacts) in GNU/Linux Ubuntu is un-usable, because one can simply not syncronise it and [dates](http://packages.ubuntu.com/dates) has been discontinued for up-to-date releases.

Meanwhile Apple ceases to provide local synchronisation capability in OS X 10.9 and [argues user should just store their data in the cloud](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23506016). - Well if we want to offer people who want to switch to a free operation system they should get an easy to use option.

Imagine you are using thunderbird and want to sync your calendar *and* addressbooks to a CalDAV/CardDAV server (on your NAS at home or your hosting provider), such as [Owncloud](http://owncloud.org/) or [DAViCal](http://www.davical.org/) you'd need to install [SoGo-connector](http://www.sogo.nu/english/downloads/frontends.html) and on top of that [Lightning](https://www.mozilla.org/projects/calendar/lightning/) and hope that all would work. Still your addresses & contacts would not be integrated in your systems calender and your appointment would only appear if your mail-client is running. - How tricky!

Many other client applications have been either discontinued or ceased developpment.

Therefore I come to the conclusion that the most simple and broadly GNU/Linux compatible solution is using [mutt](http://www.mutt.org/) with [pycarddav](http://lostpackets.de/pycarddav/) and [khal](http://lostpackets.de/khal/). - There is nothing better than the good old command line! And the most reliable solution too!

But I guess the maintainers of GNU/Linux Debian & GNU/Linux Ubuntu should finally think about ways offering *working* gui solutions for all these users that will switch from proprietary desktop to GNU/Linux!

Comment: Thanks for upvoting my post. - I finally got "reputation"! \o/